# Rotation Transformation implementation for OpenGL with 4x4 Matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, transformation, glm-math

So I am learning OpenGL and I'm try to project an image:
[image]

To be like [image]

However my implentation is resulting in:
[image]

The original tutorial is using GLM mathematics library but I wanted to try and implement it myself.

```
Matrix44& translate(float xi, float y, float z)
    {
        x[0][3] = xi;
        x[1][3] = y;
        x[2][3] = z;

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix44& rotateX(float angle)
    {
        assert(angle >= 0.0f && angle <= 360.0f);
        if (angle == 0.0f || angle == 360.f)
            return *this;

        x[1][1] = cos(angle * RAD);
        x[1][2] = sin(angle * RAD);
        x[2][1] = -sin(angle * RAD);
        x[2][2] = x[1][1];

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix44& rotateY(float angle)
    {
        assert(angle >= 0.0f && angle <= 360.0f);
        if (angle == 0.0f || angle == 360.f)
            return *this;

        x[0][0] = cos(angle * RAD);
        x[0][2] = -sin(angle * RAD);
        x[2][0] = sin(angle * RAD);
        x[2][2] = x[0][0];

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix44& rotateZ(float angle)
    {
        assert(angle >= 0.0f && angle <= 360.0f);
        if (angle == 0.0f || angle == 360.f)
            return *this;

        x[0][0] = cos(angle * RAD);
        x[0][1] = -sin(angle * RAD);
        x[1][0] = sin(angle * RAD);
        x[1][1] = x[0][0];

        return *this;
    }
```

x[][] is the 4x4 matrix. By default it is set to be the identity matrix. And in main:

```
Matrix44f model{};
        Matrix44f view{};

        model.rotateY(180).rotateX(90);
        view.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
```

To get my image but with the GLM version of:

```
glm::mat4 model;
glm::mat4 view;
model = glm::rotate( model, ( GLfloat)glfwGetTime( ) * 1.0f, glm::vec3( 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) ); 
view = glm::translate( view, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f ) );
```

I then looked at the GLM implementation: [GLM Maths Github](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.5/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl)

```
template <typename T, precision P>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<T, P> rotate
    (
        detail::tmat4x4<T, P> const & m,
        T const & angle,
        detail::tvec3<T, P> const & v
    )
    {
        T const a = angle;
        T const c = cos(a);
        T const s = sin(a);

        detail::tvec3<T, P> axis(normalize(v));
        detail::tvec3<T, P> temp((T(1) - c) * axis);

        detail::tmat4x4<T, P> Rotate(detail::tmat4x4<T, P>::_null);
        Rotate[0][0] = c + temp[0] * axis[0];
        Rotate[0][1] = 0 + temp[0] * axis[1] + s * axis[2];
        Rotate[0][2] = 0 + temp[0] * axis[2] - s * axis[1];

        Rotate[1][0] = 0 + temp[1] * axis[0] - s * axis[2];
        Rotate[1][1] = c + temp[1] * axis[1];
        Rotate[1][2] = 0 + temp[1] * axis[2] + s * axis[0];

        Rotate[2][0] = 0 + temp[2] * axis[0] + s * axis[1];
        Rotate[2][1] = 0 + temp[2] * axis[1] - s * axis[0];
        Rotate[2][2] = c + temp[2] * axis[2];

        detail::tmat4x4<T, P> Result(detail::tmat4x4<T, P>::_null);
        Result[0] = m[0] * Rotate[0][0] + m[1] * Rotate[0][1] + m[2] * Rotate[0][2];
        Result[1] = m[0] * Rotate[1][0] + m[1] * Rotate[1][1] + m[2] * Rotate[1][2];
        Result[2] = m[0] * Rotate[2][0] + m[1] * Rotate[2][1] + m[2] * Rotate[2][2];
        Result[3] = m[3];
        return Result;
    }
```

I'm so confused as to what the Result[index] accesses in the 4 x 4 matrix? Does it represent column, the row or the diagonal position?!

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: Your rotate functions override the rotation in a matrix but do not consider previous transformations. You can use your rotate functions to make an individual rotation of an identity matrix but then you still have to multiply matrices to concatenate transformations.

Comment: looks like you are inside your cube ... try to move view outside your mesh